# Codeigniter(PHP): form action doesn't go to the intended method in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think and confirm over and over again that I write the code of form action in view and the method in controller properly. However, it does not work.

In advance, my objective is that I would like to connect to controller from view via the method which I defined.

This is the problem.

When I name the method `'delete_photo'`, it works. 
This is the example in controller.

```
    public function delete_photo(){
        exit();
    }
```

And this is the example in view.

```
      <form action=<?=site_url('job/delete_photo')?> method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/*" id='edit_form'>
         <input type='submit' value='hey'>
      </form>
```

In this example, the exit action works. 
However, when I change the name into, for instance, `'edit_delete_photo'`, the exit action does not work, and at that time, the screen shows this sentence.

```
    string(18) "edide_delete_photo"
```

URL is good, I think.

Moreover, when I name the method of form action 'example' (which is not written in intended controller), it will show the almost same sentence on the screen.

```
    string(7) "example"
```

However, on the same condition, when I define the method of form action `'delete_photo'` (which is not also written in the controller), it will show this on the screen.

> 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.

For my information, the other regular method name, to name a few, edit and edit_confirm and register is working properly.

I think this is very weird.
Please tell me why this happens.

Comment: use form helper's `form_open_multipart()` method like this : `<?php echo form_open_multipart('job/delete_photo');?>`

Comment: missing quotes in `action` attr should be like this `<form action="<?=site_url('job/delete_photo');?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/*" id='edit_form'>`

Comment: Sorry, I would like to add one more explanation. The form action does not have any problem, I think because when I write the method name on URL directly, it shows the same error. The error is that when I write the proper URL + 'delete_photo', it shows 404 page not found on the screen (although the intended controller does not include the function of the method name), while when I change '/delete_photo' into '/something', it shows like 'string(9) "something" ' on the screen.

Comment: ya more details is needed here

Comment: like what more details is needed as an example?

Comment: You missed the quotes for action attribute. `<form action="<?=site_url('job/delete_photo')?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/*" id='edit_form'>` Try this as well :)